# Read JSON data in Talend through tFileInputJSON

Tags: json, talend

I have a folder which has json file. Here is sample data from the JSON file.

```
{"InstallTime": "1295768962", "Comments": "Will test without extension.", "Theme": "classic/1.0", "Version": "4.0b10pre", "id": "ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384", "Vendor": "Mozilla", "EMCheckCompatibility": "false", "Throttleable": "1", "Email": "deinspanjer@mozilla.com", "URL": "http://nighthacks.com/roller/jag/entry/the_shit_finally_hits_the", "version": "4.0b10pre", "CrashTime": "1295903735", "ReleaseChannel": "nightly", "submitted_timestamp": "2011-01-24T13:15:48.550858", "buildid": "20110121153230", "timestamp": 1295903748.551002, "Notes": "Renderers: 0x22600,0x22600,0x20400", "StartupTime": "1295768964", "FramePoisonSize": "4096", "FramePoisonBase": "7ffffffff0dea000", "AdapterRendererIDs": "0x22600,0x22600,0x20400", "Add-ons": "compatibility@addons.mozilla.org:0.7,enter.selects@agadak.net:6,{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}:1.3.3,sts-ui@sidstamm.com:0.1,masspasswordreset@johnathan.nightingale:1.04,support@lastpass.com:1.72.0,{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}:4.0b10pre", "BuildID": "20110121153230", "SecondsSinceLastCrash": "810473", "ProductName": "Firefox", "legacy_processing": 0}
```

I created a Talend job to parse the json and save it as CSV.

[image]

The job executes successfully with below message

Starting job test at 11:24 06/04/2017.

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3878
[statistics] connected
[statistics] disconnected
Job test ended at 11:24 06/04/2017. [exit code=0]
```

However, the csv file comes as blank without giving me any output. Am i missing anything while parsing the file? Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Kindly check the field `"Loop Json Query"`. The columns "InstallTime" and "Comments" should be inside the value that you specified in "Loop Json Query"

Answer (score 0):

please first try to find out what is **Loop Json Query**

Then You are able to find the solution..

[image]